# spacy similarity method doesn't not work correctly

Tags: python, similarity, word2vec, spacy, cosine-similarity

I am doing simple natural language processing using `spacy`.
I'm working on filtering out words by measuring the similarity between words.

I wrote and used the following simple code shown in the spacy documentation, but the result does not look like a [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity).

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
tokens = nlp('dog cat banana')

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        sim = token1.similarity(token2)
        print("{:>6s}, {:>6s}: {}".format(token1.text, token2.text, sim))
```

the result of code is below.

```
   dog,    dog: 1.0
   dog,    cat: 2.307269867164827e-21
   dog, banana: 0.0
   cat,    dog: 2.307269867164827e-21
   cat,    cat: 1.0
   cat, banana: -0.04468117654323578
banana,    dog: -7.828739256116838e+17
banana,    cat: -8.242222286053048e+17
banana, banana: 1.0
```

Especially, similarity between "dog" and "cat" should be about 0.8, but it is not a nd very very small value.

In addition, similarity between "dog" and "banana" is 0.0 but similarity between 'banana' and 'dog' is -7.828739256116838e+17.

I don't know how to fix it.

please help me.

Comment: Try it after re-installing en_core_web_lg model.

Comment: I don't know how to re-install it. I try to find it in spacy documentation webpage, but it failed. If you know how to re-install it, please tell me. 
thanks for your comment and help.

Comment: python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg --force

Comment: @AjaySrivastava Thanks for your help, I tried it as you mentioned it, but sadly, it still wasn't different. but thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First install large EN model (or all models).

`python3  -m spacy.en.download all`

Next, try with sample code as per documentation using,

`nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')`

If that doesnt work, Instead of above try loading,

`nlp = spacy.load('en')`

After doing above changes the result is as per documentation.

```
python3 /tmp/c.py
   dog,    dog: 1.000000078333395
   dog,    cat: 0.8016855098942641
   dog, banana: 0.2432764518408807
   cat,    dog: 0.8016855098942641
   cat,    cat: 1.0000001375986456
   cat, banana: 0.2815436412709355
banana,    dog: 0.2432764518408807
banana,    cat: 0.2815436412709355
banana, banana: 1.000000107068369
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
However, it was not solved using you solution. 
It still show wrong similiarity result different with your result.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem, finally.

just add code `import numpy as np` .

That's all.

Comment: That solution doesn't make sense at all. You're not even using numpy in your code

Comment: Ateik @Ateik Yes. As you said, I didn't use `numpy` in my code. But I solve the problem by adding that code. the library `spacy` might have dependency on the `numpy`.