# Wrong spacy similarity result

Tags: python, spacy

I just install `spacy` package in python with MacBook, and start to learn `spacy` similarity function; however, I observed wrong results.

Input:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
tokens = nlp(u'dog cat banana')

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        print(token1.text, token2.text, token1.similarity(token2))

Output:
dog dog 1.0
dog cat -1.8432091e-22
dog banana -0.00349403
cat dog -1.8432091e-22
cat cat 1.0
cat banana -1.8395509e-22
banana dog -0.00349403
banana cat -1.8395509e-22
banana banana 1.0
```

I did similar things on window10 PC, the result makes sense. I don't know what wrong with MacBook settings. I tried with `en_core_web_md` model, it still has the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.
Some people advised me to reinstall the package, but it did not really help me.
I still do not know if it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388291/spacy-similarity-method-doesnt-not-work-correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but let me offer you a work-around. You can calculate a similarity score, using:

```
import spacy
import numpy as np

nlp = spacy.load('en')
tokens = nlp(u'dog cat banana')

def similarity(token1, token2):
    return np.dot(token1.vector / token1.vector_norm, token2.vector / token2.vector_norm)

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        print(token1.text, token2.text, similarity(token1, token2))
```

If you try this, it might throw some light on the problem.